# How to hide / show visibility of HTML elements generating code from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to hide/show HTML elements in my code.
The page is generated in PHP.

Trying to semplify my code here you area a sample that show my troubles ...

```
echo '<button type="button" onclick="hide_show('.$n_images.')">Hide / show details</button>';

echo '<script  language="javascript">';
echo 'function hide_show(n_images)';
echo '  {';
echo '     element = document.getElementById("details_0");';
echo '     if (element.style.visibility == \'visible\') {';
echo '      element.style.visibility = \'hidden\'';
echo '     }';
echo '     else {';
echo '      element.style.visibility = \'visible\'';
echo '     }';
echo '  }';
echo '</script>';
```

In this case the code is working and all it's fine.

My problem is that I've several elements to hide /show and so I need to substitute the line

```
echo '     element = document.getElementById("details_0");';
```

using a while and I don't know as generalize that code ...

My final code shoud be something like this .. .

```
echo '<button type="button" onclick="hide_show('.$n_images.')">Hide / show details</button>';

echo '<script  language="javascript">';
echo 'function hide_show(n_images)';
echo '  {';
echo '   while (current_index < n_images )  {';
echo '     element = document.getElementById("details_0");'; --> this is the line I need to generalize !!!
echo '     if (element.style.visibility == \'visible\') {';
echo '      element.style.visibility = \'hidden\'';
echo '     }';
echo '     else {';
echo '      element.style.visibility = \'visible\'';
echo '     }';
echo '     current_index = current_index + 1;';
echo '   }';
echo '  }';
echo '</script>';
```

Any help / suggestions / example?

Thank you in advance!

Cesare

Comment: Hi Cesare to make it easier why not just use one php echo statement for your entire JavaScript. before your while loop, initialize current_index to 0. in your js in the line you need to generalize, getElementById("details_" + current_index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Cesare to make it easier why not just use one php echo statement for your entire JavaScript. before your while loop, initialize current_index to 0. in your js in the line you need to generalize, getElementById("details_" + current_index)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<button type="button" onclick="hide_show('.$n_images.')">Hide / show details</button>';
echo '<script  language="javascript">';
echo 'var i = 0';
echo 'function hide_show(n_images)';
echo '  {';
echo '   while (current_index < n_images )  {';
echo '     element = document.getElementById("details_" + i);'; --> this is the line I need to generalize !!!
echo '     if (element.style.visibility == \'visible\') {';
echo '      element.style.visibility = \'hidden\'';
echo '     }';
echo '     else {';
echo '      element.style.visibility = \'visible\'';
echo '     }';
echo '     current_index = current_index + 1;';
echo '     i++;';   //increment variable i value...
echo '   }';
echo '  }';
echo '</script>';
```

just initialize counter like 'var i' and add that to ever id.